# openlayers3 loadingstrategy jsonp readFeatures gives 'undefined is not a function'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp, openlayers-3

I see, the JSONP is loading in Network monitoring tab of the browser, and the function, after ajax loading the data is being called correctly from JSONP, but it gives me the following error on JSONP function call, after loading data:

> TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'layerSrc['lsBbox'].readFeatures(response)')
>
> > loadFeaturesBbox

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

 <title>The Book of OpenLayers3 - Code samples</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="progr/nm/ol.css" type="text/css">
 <script src="progr/nm/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="progr/nm/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <style type="text/css">
.map {
 width: calc(100% - 9px);
 height: 500px;
 box-shadow: 4px 4px 20px black;
 border: 3px solid blue;
 float: left;
}
.tree {
 width: auto;
 border: 3px solid red;
 background: yellow;
 float: left;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>

<dev id='mapBbox' class='map col-sm-6'></dev>

<script>
var loadFeaturesBbox = function(response){layerSrc['lsBbox'].addFeatures(layerSrc['lsBbox'].readFeatures(response));};
var layerSrc = {
 lsBbox: new ol.source.Vector({
  format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
  loader: function(extent, resolution, projection){
   $.ajax({
    url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&request=GetFeature&version=1.1.0&typename=osm%3Awater_areas&outputFormat=text%2Fjavascript&format_options=callback%3AloadFeaturesBbox&srsname=EPSG%3A3857&bbox='+extent.join(','),
    dataType: 'jsonp'
   })
  },
  strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
  projection: 'EPSG:3857'
 })
};

var layers = {
 OSM: new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()}),
 lsBbox: new ol.layer.Vector({
  source: layerSrc['lsBbox'],
  style: new ol.style.Style({
   stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
    color: 'green',
    width: 2
   })
  })
 })
};

var view = new ol.View({
 center: ol.proj.transform([-75.923853, 45.428736], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
 maxZoom: 19,
 zoom: 10
});

var maps = {
 mapBbox: new ol.Map({
  target: 'mapBbox',
  renderer: 'canvas',
  layers: [layers['OSM'], layers['lsBbox']],
  view: view
 })
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So, and the loaded vector data by JSONP call doesn't display on the map.
How can I solve this problem?
OpenLayers Version: v3.20.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no readFeatures method on the vector source see: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html
You need to call that on its format, so source.getFormat().readFeatures

Comment: I hava a struggle, understanding api docs and thanx, It worked! When I am reading api docs for openlayers, I don't understand 90% of what's being said there. I guess, after finishing reading the book, I will have some better understanding of the api documentation.